# How to make the scroll button appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already have a button that smoothly scrolls up. But I need it to disappear when there is no scroll and appear when there is a scroll without jquery.

```css
.scrollup {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkNki.png);
}
.scrollup:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quasi recusandae minima corrupti possimus maiores quaerat eveniet, odit, aut rem asperiores adipisci! Culpa minima facere voluptatibus eveniet, ex nisi veniam accusamus vitae modi rerum provident repudiandae, architecto doloribus a nihil. Architecto itaque laboriosam rem dignissimos accusantium eum? Nostrum, eius nam est, labore dolores veritatis qui vel fugiat a minus incidunt debitis ipsum aliquam odio reiciendis architecto ducimus pariatur voluptate ipsam iure obcaecati sunt. Repellat necessitatibus doloremque eaque delectus soluta quis nemo rem minus sunt a. Esse dolorem doloremque accusamus repellat unde quos quod non tempora repellendus neque eum sequi laborum a praesentium aperiam perferendis totam, ipsum hic sint veniam? Pariatur veritatis unde sapiente, consectetur, velit veniam ab blanditiis voluptatibus voluptatum quasi iusto! Porro, dolores eaque itaque impedit in iste pariatur! Dolores quis enim veritatis eos? Delectus et aliquid voluptate quos accusantium doloremque, temporibus harum porro eos possimus architecto amet doloribus eius illum omnis expedita, nesciunt, consequatur rem voluptatibus incidunt cupiditate molestiae tenetur. Earum iusto beatae officiis corporis, quas eum natus dolorem veniam aspernatur ratione sunt repudiandae, porro ex eligendi obcaecati alias non reiciendis numquam facere vitae perspiciatis! Iste nisi quia ut, inventore vel excepturi labore omnis, beatae reiciendis aut earum amet in totam est, iure officia odio quo quas provident accusamus laudantium nihil repellat? Molestiae eos natus sint voluptatibus porro nam nulla dolore consequatur exercitationem! Quidem ad rem cumque aperiam, aut accusamus minima aspernatur expedita, corrupti quaerat neque at nemo quo tenetur suscipit eius necessitatibus iste vitae repellendus sint illo natus culpa? Et culpa voluptatem alias dignissimos maiores a exercitationem sequi eveniet odio illo ab sed quis, fugit repudiandae architecto aliquid similique corrupti fugiat sit rem itaque molestiae. Non quia numquam, aliquam ducimus illum inventore quaerat voluptates repellendus eius, iusto, hic optio maxime magni nisi possimus perferendis minima deserunt exercitationem qui rem iste. Vero sapiente assumenda saepe temporibus iusto! Eligendi veniam dolorem odio, velit hic nisi ut saepe maxime nobis nesciunt sed, reprehenderit repudiandae dolorum beatae quod. Quisquam porro saepe deleniti et architecto, ipsam sit debitis aspernatur unde possimus recusandae vel numquam eaque perferendis eos eveniet inventore tenetur quo harum cumque. Amet corporis illum, natus obcaecati ad minus ab alias soluta deserunt dicta corrupti excepturi, exercitationem vel repellat quasi autem commodi, similique modi impedit sed nam dolor quas! Ipsa mollitia deleniti consequatur sed, cupiditate nam, optio necessitatibus fugiat incidunt velit facere veniam pariatur quis, officia delectus rem corporis at labore? Veniam tenetur dolorum quibusdam nemo dicta commodi voluptate ad sunt omnis nisi tempora officiis magni, accusamus in culpa a temporibus eaque fuga voluptas aut, quas ex rerum autem. Impedit libero sequi quae facere porro fugiat tempora ipsum reprehenderit alias dignissimos adipisci quod exercitationem maiores deserunt quos dolorem, possimus amet necessitatibus praesentium ipsam quam nihil? Libero nemo soluta delectus labore numquam nulla placeat molestias, atque veniam hic minima iste illo saepe consequuntur harum, reprehenderit modi fuga, laudantium rerum consequatur voluptatum. Beatae veritatis adipisci veniam sint? Laborum beatae sint qui natus reiciendis quo aperiam dolorem, doloremque inventore, obcaecati animi facere. Autem provident aut pariatur eveniet aliquam dicta nobis facilis quam facere molestias totam repellat illum placeat similique saepe, doloremque cum quia. Deleniti facilis minus aperiam in modi, placeat quo similique consequatur quisquam alias necessitatibus porro, totam quibusdam at! Dignissimos corporis eos, voluptatibus eaque nobis laborum quia aperiam impedit! Corrupti hic odit eum? Itaque, maxime eos. Debitis eius ea praesentium, aliquam repellat libero pariatur similique consectetur quas est deserunt! Dicta laboriosam praesentium dolores? Minima quo magni, minus debitis sit quod hic ullam eveniet nobis ut error facilis veniam explicabo iure aliquam adipisci fugiat. Aperiam voluptatem incidunt cupiditate explicabo reiciendis aliquid nihil quaerat laboriosam illum, repellendus odit in corporis iusto quibusdam autem facilis tenetur nam qui est reprehenderit? Earum alias sint eaque deleniti, ut inventore error praesentium facilis dolorem molestiae voluptas veritatis cum, repudiandae sequi fuga ipsum incidunt a, ex architecto aspernatur unde? Consequatur, error soluta facere corrupti vel rerum possimus enim dolorum consectetur qui eius neque debitis ipsum tempora, accusamus magnam praesentium perspiciatis, quos necessitatibus? Quam fugiat rerum ullam quisquam ipsum nobis numquam illo porro saepe sed repellat hic obcaecati, velit laborum quos maiores repudiandae odit dignissimos debitis ab aliquid dicta neque veniam? Tempora fugit temporibus veniam modi sed esse ab alias nemo possimus, dolores a suscipit repellat repellendus earum aperiam assumenda eligendi fuga! Error natus, magnam, et magni commodi nulla officiis voluptatum voluptas facere, deleniti incidunt ipsum vitae eum ducimus culpa qui quod harum sapiente corporis accusantium? Exercitationem corporis in ab quas sed error consequuntur consectetur officiis quasi unde, debitis excepturi temporibus voluptatibus labore dolore aspernatur ut dignissimos. Culpa fugit repudiandae corporis sapiente! Repellendus voluptas tenetur vitae quos omnis odit ipsam culpa! Sunt quis suscipit aliquam corporis non doloremque. Voluptatem qui, vero ullam voluptatibus, quam, vitae molestias odio sunt harum accusamus unde ducimus aut culpa distinctio iusto odit? Deserunt, omnis eligendi? Quaerat officia minima quam quos voluptatibus sequi quod consequuntur distinctio? Placeat architecto soluta quibusdam quod natus necessitatibus deserunt atque possimus labore? Quisquam molestias vitae quis repellendus sequi ipsa necessitatibus dignissimos facere maxime totam cumque, earum, possimus et eum aspernatur aperiam! Eligendi quas quis quo quibusdam. Repudiandae ipsa consequuntur aut explicabo fugiat deserunt. Velit aliquam quia accusamus modi ut? Reiciendis est consequatur ipsam atque voluptas, doloremque repudiandae! Fuga voluptates ratione, iure quaerat excepturi perferendis fugit veniam aspernatur, vitae ipsam dolor ut facere voluptatem dolorum deleniti perspiciatis quae debitis rem temporibus nemo voluptatum quis nesciunt corporis sequi! Aliquid ullam ratione odio similique provident. Voluptate soluta laboriosam ab eum et. Voluptate eum excepturi deserunt rem sunt est dicta qui officia praesentium vitae fuga neque assumenda hic saepe alias amet, distinctio aperiam? Fugiat id distinctio saepe esse tempore neque incidunt iure nihil deleniti, soluta laudantium, recusandae voluptatem deserunt tempora ullam architecto sit, explicabo praesentium autem labore ipsum itaque natus! Alias, ipsa? Saepe expedita sint molestiae temporibus odit reprehenderit praesentium, exercitationem architecto suscipit porro libero laborum aut alias rem. A dolore suscipit illo sunt mollitia molestias ad inventore reiciendis provident at minus, laborum odit necessitatibus ab numquam reprehenderit quaerat ducimus voluptatum accusantium nihil officia libero culpa. Magni!</p>

<a onclick="window.scroll({ top: 0,left: 0,behavior: 'smooth' });" class="scrollup">Top</a>
```

Comment: This can only be done with JavaScript. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself before posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

Using scrollTop and onscroll function, you can solve it easily. Try once.
mainDiv. scrollTop returns how many pixels vertically scrolled.Disable or enable button onscroll event listener based on scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

i have done this work recently, and i create this function. i hope it help you

```
function showBtnToTop(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 767){// 768 medium screen width
        if (window.scrollY >= x){ // x is a number, and it is the position when the button disappear
            $('#gotop').css("opacity", "100");// gotop is the id of the button
        }else{
            $('#gotop').css("opacity", "0");
        }
    }else{ // don't show the button in small screen
        $('#gotop').css("opacity", "0");
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", showBtnToTop);
```

use this JS function to selcet the btn
`let a = document.getElementById("");`
and change the css property like this:
`a.style.color = "blue";`

Comment: Yes it works, but it requires a connection jquery. I need without jquery.

Comment: yes, in the example above. i use Jquery for select the button and change css property, so you can replace the Jquery code with these two function `document.getElementById("")` and `a.style.color`.